# Prometheus relabel_configs - multiple target labels

Tags: prometheus

I'm using Prometheus with `file_sd_configs` sources.  Using this approach labels can be extracted from the filename.  E.g.:

```
file_sd_configs:
  - files:
    - /etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_http_prod.yml
    - /etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_http_dev.yml
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_filepath]
    regex: "/etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_http_(dev|tst|uat|prod)\\.yml"
    target_label: env
```

I'd like to take this a step further and populate multiple target labels using a single Regex.  E.g.

```
file_sd_configs:
  - files:
    - /etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_http_prod.yml
    - /etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_http_dev.yml
    - /etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_db_prod.yml
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_filepath]
    regex: "/etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_([^_]+)_(dev|tst|uat|prod)\\.yml"
    target_label: type
    replacement: $2
    target_label: env
```

Is this a supported method or does the source and regex need to be specified multiple times?

Comment: Do you know you can just put labels inside those files? https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/file-sd/

Comment: @anemyte yes, I knew that.  Within each file there are hundreds of targets and, although they're grouped by common labels, there are still many groups.  Each of those groups would require an identical variable defined.  This method allows me to assign a label to every target in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following relabeling rules should create `type` and `env` labels based on the `__meta_filepath` label value:

```yaml
- source_labels: [__meta_filepath]
  regex: "etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_([^_]+)_(dev|tst|uat|prod)\\.yml"
  replacement: "$1"
  target_label: type
- source_labels: [__meta_filepath]
  regex: "etc/prometheus/targets/hostname_([^_]+)_(dev|tst|uat|prod)\\.yml"
  replacement: "$2"
  target_label: env
```

Basically it contains two relabeling rules with the same `regex` part, but with distinct `replacement` and `target_label` parts. This relabeling rule can be debugged [here](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/target-relabel-debug?relabel_configs=-+source_labels%3A+%5B__meta_filepath%5D%0D%0A++regex%3A+%22etc%2Fprometheus%2Ftargets%2Fhostname_%28%5B%5E_%5D%2B%29_%28dev%7Ctst%7Cuat%7Cprod%29%5C%5C.yml%22%0D%0A++replacement%3A+%22%241%22%0D%0A++target_label%3A+type%0D%0A-+source_labels%3A+%5B__meta_filepath%5D%0D%0A++regex%3A+%22etc%2Fprometheus%2Ftargets%2Fhostname_%28%5B%5E_%5D%2B%29_%28dev%7Ctst%7Cuat%7Cprod%29%5C%5C.yml%22%0D%0A++replacement%3A+%22%242%22%0D%0A++target_label%3A+env&metric=%7B__meta_filepath%3D%22etc%2Fprometheus%2Ftargets%2Fhostname_foo_prod.yml%22%7D).